# No data when perform post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

AccountController.cs

```
namespace IndividueleOpdracht.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View(new Account());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(Account model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View();

            if (model.Login())
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "News");
            }

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Account.cs

```
namespace IndividueleOpdracht.Models
{
    public class Account
    {
        [Required]
        public string Email;

        [Required]
        public string Password;

        public bool Login()
        {
            if (Email == "test" && Password == "test")
            {
            return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Login.cshtml

```
@model IndividueleOpdracht.Models.Account

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-signin" }))
{
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h2>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @type = "email", @id = "inputEmail", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email adres" })
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Wachtwoord</label>
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @id = "inputPassword", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Wachtwoord" })
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Onthoud mij
        </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
}
```

When i do a post, it says the model parameter is empty. Email is null and password is also.

ModelState.IsValid is true.

Can somebody tell me what i am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: you shouldn't be specifying the `@id`, MVC gives them IDs automatically.

Comment: and you should use `@Html.LabelFor()` instead of writing your own

Comment: Id is for the labels? If I remove the ids will it fix the problem?

Comment: Did you fill the form fields before hitting submit ?

Comment: i'm pretty sure it keys off `name`, not ID, but i'm just giving some other advice that you should do in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

Change your view model class to have **set/get** and make it public properties.

```
public class Account
{
    [Required]
    public string Email {set;get;};

    [Required]
    public string Password {set;get;};

}
```

If you don't keep them as properties (with `set`), MVC model binder canno't set the values to those properties after reading from the posted form data.

Also, to see the validation summary, you can use the `Html.ValidationSummary()` method. So when model validation fails, you will see a list of property validation errors.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Email)
    <input type="submit" />
}
```